# Parsing seconds from mm.ss.00 string

Tags: string, excel, time, excel-formula, vba

I have a lot of elapsed time records in the form of `mm.ss.00`. For example if elapsed time was `1min 44.72sec`, data becomes `1.44.72`. I want to convert these data into pure seconds data. Let me give some examples:

```
|mm.ss.00        |seconds        |
|:--------------:|:-------------:|
|1.44.72         |104.72
|2.5.32          |125.32
|0.59.12         |59.12
```

I can assure that time records never exceed 59min 59.99sec, so you can easily assume 1 or 2 digits before first dot(`.`) must be minutes.

Comment: It's not clear what format your data is currently in, and what you want to convert it to. More examples may help. Eg, if the data is 1 minute and 3 seconds is that currently shown as '1min 3.00sec' or '1min 03.00sec' or '1min 3sec'. Then explain how you want it to appear (1.03.00' or '1.3' or... ?)

Comment: @PaulG I added more examples. Thank you

Comment: @pnuts Can you register your answer? I want to adopt your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))+60*LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1))
```

This treats the likes of `1.44.72` as a string and manipulates it to strip off the numeric characters up to and including the first full stop (period in USA). The part including and after the plus sign may not be required if the minutes are to be ignored as it takes the number before the first full stop (minutes) converts to seconds and adds that to the seconds and hundredths of seconds from the first part of the formula.

The addition process converts the text result from string manipulation into a numeric format, though this could be achieved for seconds and hundredths of seconds in other ways.

Comment: I'd always recommend avoiding hard string manipulation if at all possible, it's generally more "fragile" and harder to maintain than other options .. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you wish to convert and run this short macro:

```
Sub Fixer()
    Dim r As Range, N As Long
    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Text, ".")
        If UBound(ary) = 2 Then
            r.Clear
            r.Value = CLng(ary(1))
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

***EDIT#1:***

This is a *VBA* macro.  Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#2**

Based on your updated post, here is the updated macro:

```
Sub Fixer()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Text, ".")
        If UBound(ary) = 2 Then
            r.Clear
            r.Value = 60 * CDbl(ary(0)) + CDbl((ary(1) & "." & ary(2)))
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about VB. is it VB?

Comment: @pnuts  I will match the VBA to meet the **new** requirements.

Comment: Interesting take, however, using VBA for this seems a bit "overkill?" ;) maybe that's just me, though .. lol

Comment: @Ditto I would use VBA if you wanted to convert "in place".............without a helper column.

Comment: Wow. @Gary'sStudent thank you for your kind explanation. I would start studying VBA thanks for you.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"min ",":"),"sec",""))*24*60*60
```

1) Use Substitute to remove the "min" and "sec" text, it's "useless" and just gets in the way. Also, add a : to the first gap to help Excel understand the format.
2) convert to an internal Excel date/time code/value.
3) multiple my 24 (24 hours in a day) *60 (60 min in an hour) *60 (60 sec in a minute) to get the number of seconds involved.

** Sorry, think I misread the input format ..

the above assumes the data is coming in like "1min 44.72sec" .. 
if the data is just "1.44.72" .. use this one instead:

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,".",":",1))*24*60*60
```

Similar idea, convert the first period to a colon, then convert to an internal Excel time, then convert to seconds. ;)

Comment: ? hmm, oh .. misread the question a bit :) don't need the substitute then .. lol

Comment: Nah, question is clear, I just misread his input format :) I've editted my answer to include both .. ;)